# Replace output occurrences

Tags: text-processing, replace

Let's say I have this output:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
```

and I want to replace the first two zeros (`00`) with (`01`).  What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
$ sed 's/^00/01/' file.txt
```

#### Details

The above will look through each line of file `file.txt` and replace any occurrences of `00` that are anchored to the beginning of the line (that's what the caret, `^`, does). For each occurrence it will be replaced with `01`.

The function I'm using within `sed` is called search and replace (`s/../../`).

Comment: You're right, I've removed my post and upvoted yours.